# Python gpgme non-ascii text handling

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to encrypt-decrypt a text via GPG using pygpgme, while it works for western characters decryption fails on a Russian text. I use GPG suite on Mac to decrypt e-mail.
Here's the code I use to produce encrypted e-mail body, note that I tried to encode message in Unicode but it didn't make any difference. I use Python 2.7.

Please help, I must say I am new to Python.

```
ctx = gpgme.Context()
ctx.armor = True
key = ctx.get_key('0B26AE38098')

payload = 'Просто тест'

#plain = BytesIO(payload.encode('utf-8'))
plain = BytesIO(payload)
cipher = BytesIO()

ctx.encrypt([key], gpgme.ENCRYPT_ALWAYS_TRUST, plain, cipher)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here. You really should read the [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), but I'll try to explain.

---

```
payload = 'Просто тест'
```

Python 2.x source code is, by default, Latin-1. But your source clearly isn't Latin-1, because Latin-1 doesn't even *have* those characters. What happens if you write `Просто тест` in one program (like a text editor) as UTF-8, then read it in another program (like Python) as Latin-1? You get `ÐÑÐ¾ÑÑÐ¾ ÑÐµÑÑ`. So, what you're doing is creating a string full of nonsense. If you're using ISO-8859-5 rather than UTF-8, it'll be different nonsense, but still nonsense

So, first and foremost, you need to find out what encoding you *did* use in your text editor. It's *probably* UTF-8, if you're on a Mac, but don't just guess; find out.

---

Second, you have to tell Python what encoding you used. You do that by using an [encoding declaration](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). For example, if your text editor uses UTF-8, add this line to the top of your code:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

---

One you fix that, `payload` will be a byte string, encoded in whatever encoding your text editor uses. But you can't encode already-encoded byte strings, only Unicode strings.

Python 2.x will let you call `encode` on them anyway, but it's not very useful—what it will do is first decode the string to Unicode using `sys.getdefaultencoding`, so it can then encode that. That's unlikely to be what you want.

The right way to fix this is to make `payload` a Unicode string in the first place, by using a Unicode literal. Like this:

```
payload = u'Просто тест'
```

---

Now, finally, you can actually encode the payload to UTF-8, which you did perfectly correctly in your first attempt:

```
plain = BytesIO(payload.encode('utf-8'))
```

---

Finally, you're encrypting UTF-8 plain text with GPG. When you decrypt it on the other side, make sure to decode it as UTF-8 there as well, or again you'll probably see nonsense.

Comment: My python code already had #coding=utf-8 line in it, and I did read the "Unicode HOWTO" - didn't help. I still have the problem and I tend to think now that py-gpgme lib is broken. BTW, if my payload comes from stdio how do I convert/make sure it's unicode using python?

Comment: @user3321467: First, did you use a Unicode string literal rather than a plain string literal? If not, your code will still likely not work, as explained in the answer.

Comment: @user3321467: For your second question: `payload.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)`. As explained [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.encoding), for a file connected to a terminal, `encoding` "gives the encoding that the terminal is likely to use (that information might be incorrect if the user has misconfigured the terminal)". So, unless you've screwed up your Terminal.app settings, or you're redirecting stdio from something other than the terminal (e.g., `echo "blah" | python myscript.py` or `python myscript.py < foo.txt`) this works.

Comment: @user3321467: One last thing: Is your `coding` directive either the very first line, or the very second line where the first line is `#!/usr/bin/env python` or similar? If not, it has no effect.

Comment: @user3321467: Anyway, it's highly unlikely that this is a bug in `py-gpgme`. That library does not care about what the bytes that you give it mean; it just treats them as bytes. You can throw random binary data at it, and it will encrypt and decrypt that data. So if you give it the right UTF-8 encoded bytes, encrypt and decrypt them, you'll get the same bytes back; if you then decode it as UTF-8, you'll get your original string.